# i am writing a calendar to store birthdays with a multiset of birthday objects i am new to iterators and get a compiler error when using find()

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

> I am making a calendar that stores birthdays in a multiset. The
>   multiset actually stores   birthday object pointers. I cant figure out
>   how to use the find function with an iterator to pointers on a
>   multiset

```
 MultiSet::MultiSet(string fName,string lName,int d,int m, int y):dateAndName(fName,lName,d,m,y)
    {
    }
    void MultiSet::searchByName( Birthday *a)
    {
        multiset<Birthday *>::iterator result;
```

> ```
>      *I am getting a compiler error on this next line it reads*
>       Error   1   error C2664:  : 
>       cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Birthday' to 'Birthday       *const &.
> ```

```
     **
```

> *I am just not really sure how to use 
>             the find function with an iterator to pointers*

**

```
    result=nameSet.find(&a);

    if(result!=dateSet.end())
        cout<<result->getFirstName();
    else
        cout<<"Person not found. "<<endl;
}
void MultiSet::addToList(Birthday *a)
{
    nameSet.insert(a);
    dateSet.insert(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `a` variable is a pointer to `Birthday`, and your multiset contains pointers to `Birthday`, so instead of:

```
nameSet.find(&a); // ERROR! nameSet is a container of Birthday*
                  // objects, and not of Birthday** objects
```

You should do:

```
nameSet.find(a); // OK: Here you just look for a pointer to Birthday
```

Comment: when i do that it says "IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands"

Comment: @AlexGimson: On what line?

Comment: @AlexGimson: How do you declare `nameSet`?

Comment: @AlexGimson: Is it only intellisense complaining, or is the compiler refusing to compile? If so, what is its exact error message?

Comment: its refusing to compile. Error 1 error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Could you try declaring `result` as `multiset<Birthday *, CompareName>::iterator result;`? (to match the declaration of `nameSet`)

Comment: @AlexGimson: I suspect the reason is that you do not specify the custom comparator in the definition of `result` (see my previous comment)